# Dropzone.js loads files dropped in Firefox, but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, dropzone.js

I wrote a simple [image pastebin app](https://gitlab.com/stemid/python-imagebin) using Dropzone.js, but drag and drop of files does not work in Firefox.

It does work in Chrome, leading me to believe this is a fixable issue.

In firefox any dropped files simply load and the browser tries to display them on the local FS.

All the code is in the linked git repo, but here is a [direct link to the JS code](https://gitlab.com/stemid/python-imagebin/-/blob/main/js/upload.js?ref_type=heads) in particular.

As you can see I've been trying different ways to workaround this issue, including stopping events on the div#dropzone, the body and the window.

```js
window.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Edit: This was a FF issue. I'm on Fedora Silverblue with Flatpak Firefox. I tried the old system Firefox, didn't work. System FF asked me to refresh settings, did that, then I entered troubleshoot mode just to be safe, then drag and drop upload started working on multiple sites! So this is an FF issue and I'm closing the question.

Comment: is there an error message in ff?

Comment: Nothing, and even if there were it loads the file so the console reloads. The app is online at imagebin.sydit.se actually, you can see for yourself.

Comment: there's a "persist logs" options in FF devtools.

Comment: yeah I enabled that, no new logs.

Comment: might be able to pause with an onbeforeunload handler, but FF could simply block your file drops for security.

Comment: This worked on saturday when I started using dropzone.js. Otherwise I wouldn't have continued. But then on the way something happened, I likely did something wrong, and I didn't test drag and drop until after I deployed and saw that it doesn't work. Honestly now in hindsight dropzone.js works really poorly. In chrome I can only upload one file at the time, and I have to drop it around the edges. And in FF it used to work and now it doesn't. I just don't get it.

Comment: Actually on second glance it looks like a FF issue. I just tried drag and drop in another app that I know works and it doesn't work there either. It doesn't load the files, but that can be prevented, it does nothing. Searching online I see others with the same problem in Firefox. Some have it on Windows due to UAC but I'm on Linux.

Comment: well it can work in ff, https://jsfiddle.net/bevhd7gz/

Answer (score 0):

This was a FF issue. I'm on Fedora Silverblue with Flatpak Firefox. I tried the old system Firefox, didn't work. System FF asked me to refresh settings, did that, then I entered troubleshoot mode just to be safe, then drag and drop upload started working on multiple sites! So this is an FF issue and I'm closing the question.

And a proper solution was to run Flatseal and modify the permissions of the Firefox Flatpak to allow access to all files i my homedir. Or whatever dir you're dragging files from.